# Perl alarm() equivalent in C?

Tags: c, linux, perl, alarm

What is the Perl's `alarm()` equivalent in C for Linux? AFAIK there is no native `alarm` function in Windows, but Perl made a workaround which I am not really curious about.

For the ones who don't know about `alarm`: [Perl alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

**EDIT:** I actually need alarm with milisecond precision. And the one that I can use in a thread(in a multithreaded app).

Comment: Isn't it just [`alarm(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alarm)?

Comment: Realtime timers syscalls: timer_create(), setitimer(), timer_delete() are what it seems you want.  The timer_create() man page has an example.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_delete.html

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
unsigned int alarm (unsigned int secs, unsigned int usecs) {
   struct itimerval old, new;
   new.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
   new.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;

   // usecs should always be < 1000000
   secs += usecs / 1000000;
   usecs = usecs % 1000000;

   // set the alarm timer
   new.it_value.tv_usec = (long int) usecs;
   new.it_value.tv_sec = (long int) secs;

   // type ITIMER_REAL for wallclock timer
   if (setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &new, &old) < 0)
     return 0;
   else
     return old.it_value.tv_sec;
 }
```

see: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-an-Alarm.html